# Unity3D - Rigidbody phasing through platform collider when platform is rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate a kinematic platform and slide an object with 0 friction on top of the platform. Unfortunately when rotating the platform, the object is phasing through it.

**Here's what I tried:**

**1:** I changed the mass of the platform. (No effect)

**2:** I changed the platform collision detection to continuous speculative and the cubes detection to continuous dynamic. (No effect)

**Reference:**

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwVLJ.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occur because the cube does not inherit the planes transforms rotation.

A simple solution to this is on collison make the cube a child of the plane i collids with.

```
void OnCollisonEnter(Collision collision) {
   gameObject.setParent(collision.gameObject);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If I would want to make the small cube jump when the platform is rotated fast (so it is launched up), is there a way that would work for this, I edited to question now.

Comment: Well that's a whole different question. Calculate the amount the plane rotated and the time from start to finish. Based on those parameters you could determine a launch force on the `Rigidbody`. That should do the trick.